# Undefined output in console.log(err.message)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

```
useEffect(function () {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const res = await fetch(
          `http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${apiKeyOmdb}&s=${query}`
        );
        const data = await res.json();
        console.log("data", data);

        if (data.Response === "False") {
          console.log("False");
          throw new Error("test1");
        }

        setMovies(data.Search);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        setError(err);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Hello everyone Please help me with the problem: when output to console.log(err.message), undefined is output, although I throw the error throw new Error("test1");

Comment: Is `"False"` logged? (If not, maybe the error isn't yours, and it's not an `Error` object but something else.) Also, what do you get when you log the error as a whole (`console.error(error)`)?

Comment: What would be the output of `console.log(err)`?

Comment: The following is output: 
False
undefined

If you write console.error(err), the following is output:
{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: 'div', key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}
$$typeof
: 
Symbol(react.element)
key
: 
null
props
: 
{className: 'error', children: Array(2)}
ref
: 
null
type
: 
"div"
_owner
: 
null
_store
: 
{validated: true}
_self
: 
Error {}
_source
: 
{fileName: 'C:\\React\\ultimate-react-course\\10. Thinking in Rea…mposition, and Reusability\\use-popcorn\\src\\App.js', lineNumber: 151, columnNumber: 5}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object

Comment: Why does the text of test1 not get into catch???? :(

Comment: Do you have a component called `Error` by chance? The output doesn't look like the builtin Error object.

Comment: @knittl yes i have this component: 

function Error({ errorMessage }) {
  return (
    <div className="error">
      <span>⛔</span>
      {errorMessage}
    </div>
  );
}

Comment: @AntonKobelev so `throw new Error` isn't throwing an error, but throwing your component instead. Rename your component, its name is clashing with the browsers' builtin Error object.

Comment: @knittl thank you very much!!! That was the problem!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a component named `Error` which is conflicting with the browsers' `Error`. `throw new Error` is throwing your Component, not an error object.

Either rename your component or change the throw statement to `throw new window.Error('test1');`.